# PyQt5: How to drag text from QTextEdit into a QlistView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextedit, qlistview

I'm currently building a GUI, to which I would like to add the possibility to drag a string from a QTextEdit, and drop it into a QListView so that the dropped string creates a new row.

But sadly I'm a bit confused with what I should be doing. There are tons of examples, but I can't see clearly what I should be doing.

From what I understand I have to reimplement functions but right now I'm more of an headless chicken.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import testing_ground_lib, sys


class ListModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def supportedDropActions(self):
        <MAYBE DO STUFF HERE>

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, modelIndex):
        <MAYBE DO STUFF HERE>

class testing_ground(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, testing_ground_lib.Ui_TestWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.list_model = ListModel(0, 1, self)
        self.inputs_list.setModel(self.list_model)



sys.argv = ['']
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
testing_ground = testing_ground()
testing_ground.show()
app.exec_()
```

*testing_ground_lib* is just the UI generated through QtDesigner, in which we have *self.inputs_list.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)* and where my QTextEdit widget is defined (*self.req_editor*)

In reimplemented dropMimeData, I tried to print stuff just to see how it works but it did not do anything when I was trying to drop my string within QListView.

It is clear to me that I have to implement something that would append a row in ListView on drop of the string, and set the new item with the text from the string, I just can't get what is the starting point.

**EDIT** : after further investigation, I managed to make the item acceptable by adding :

```
    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['text/plain']
```

in my ListModel class. Now I think I just have to properly reimplement dropMimeData and I think all will be good. I'll update this post if I manage to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to drag the highlighted text in a QTextEdit and drop it into a QListView, adding a new row with that text. Subclass QListView and reimplement `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent`, and `dropEvent`. In the `dropEvent`, add the new item with `QStandardItemModel.appendRow()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class ListView(QListView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(0, 1))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept() if event.mimeData().hasText() else event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept() if event.mimeData().hasText() else event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            self.model().appendRow(QStandardItem(event.mimeData().text()))
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout(window)
    hbox.addWidget(QTextEdit())
    hbox.addWidget(ListView())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did manage yesterday evening to have something working but not "as clean" as your code. Thank you very much.